# What is CSP blocked URI "c" and "file"

Tags: content-security-policy

I am getting the following two kinds of violation in my CSP report

1. Blocked URI "file"

   "violated-directive":"img-src",
   "disposition":"report",
   "blocked-uri":"file",
   "status-code":0,
   "script-sample":""
2. Blocked URI "c"

   "violated-directive":"img-src",
   "disposition":"report",
   "blocked-uri":"c",
   "status-code":0,
   "script-sample":""

I am not able to understand what these two uri are blocked and what is the reason for blocking.

If anyone has idea about this it would be very helpful

Comment: Looks like requests for a wrong image url. Very strange `"status-code":0`, it should be 200 if 'Ok', or 404/403 if 'Not found'.

Comment: Exactly thats what I couldn't understand why this is reported

Comment: Do you save visitor's IP address and User Agens with violation reports? Those can shed a lights. If IP belongs to public hostings (check via whois) - it's some bots wrongly parse your web page. Sometimes their names contains in User Agent